# Connecting mysql database with tcl script

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl script..I have a task of connecting MySQL database and perform simple queries like creating table, inserting values etc with the tcl script.I tried searching in google for the same.But could not find the useful info.Can someone please help me here..Please show me with the examples.

Comment: This is not the kind of questions StackOverflow deals with. To be answerable here, a question should be about a specific problem with an existing program. http://wiki.tcl.tk/6051 should be helpful, though.

Comment: Int's interesting to speculate on how the OP searched Google, as entering "tcl mysql" into it yielded the above page as the second hit. I think he should take a look at [TDBC](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tdbc) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to source .so file in your tcl prompt like below.

```
load <filepath.so> (NOTE : it is server dependent, if it is linux you need to load linux so file, if it is solaris, then load solaris so file )
```

then use below command to connect mysql server.

```
set sql_handle [mysqlconnect -host hostname -user sql_accountname -password password -db databasename]
```

Using sql_handle , you can process your sql operations.